# Generate permutation group $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm getting confused by the order of things.  So I think it should have 3!=6 elements.

$S_n$ = {id, (12), (23), (13), **Here's where I get confused...** (231), (312)?}

Is that right?  Can someone please explain why/why not?

Comment: You can think as $(12) = (12)(3)$. List all element of $S_3$: id, (12), (13), (23), (123), (132).

Comment: @GAVD are (123) and (132) equivalent to what I have written?

Comment: @VinnyChase Assuming I'm understanding your notation, the elements $(231)$ and $(312)$ are the same permutation, so you're missing an element.

Comment: @QuinnGreicius why are they the same element?

Comment: $(231)$ is the same as $(312),$ since in both cases $2$ goes to $3$ and $3$ to $1$ and $1$ to $2$. You need $3$ going to $1$ and $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $3$. That is $(123).$

Comment: @VinnyChase Yep, $(123) = (231) = (312)$ because they make the same permutaion.

Comment: @GAVD so is (213) what I need to switch in for it? and does (123) being done on $x_1x_2x_3$ = $x_3x_2x_1$? I think I'm just confused by the notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Rule**It can be given in following steps;

**Step 1** obtain the possible order of elements of S$_{3}$ here it is 1,2 and 3.

**Step 2** firstly write identity and two cycle then three cycle.
{(1)(12)(13)(23)(123)(132)}=  6 elements

**How To Avoid Confusion** Write the element then try to write its inverse element.then take another element,I always use this path